# Can a variable be a part of a filename that is to be opened?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way in PHP to open a file based on a variable for the filename? Basically what I want to is this:

```
$file = file('data.txt');
$needle = array("one", "two", "three");
$haystack = array("one", "three");

foreach($needle as $value){
  $pos = strpos($haystack, $value);

if($pos !== false){
  $filename = "$value.txt";
  file_put_contents($filename, $file);
}
```

The values of $needle are the names of .txt files. It works up until file_put_contents. $filename is not valid and I have searched all over for a solution to this and tried everything I can think of. I want to load the array value, say "one" with the .txt extension as a filename, depending on if the value was found in the haystack. Is there any way to do this without doing an if statement for each filename? I would rather handle it with a loop if possible.

Edited to swap the parameters.

Edit, new code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
$needle = array("one", "two", "three");
$haystack = array("one", "three");
$files = array_intersect($needle, $haystack);
foreach ($files as $value) {
  $newfilename = "$value.txt";
  var_dump($newfilename);
  file_put_contents($newfilename, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the parameters of file_put_contents():

> int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )

So you need to swap them:

```
file_put_contents($filename, $file);
```

Second thing is, that you're doing a strpos() on an array, but that function is (as its name says) for strings - what you want is in_array():

```
foreach ($needle as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $haystack) {
        $filename = "$value.txt";
        file_put_contents($filename, $file);
    }
}
```

You can even enhance this a bit more by using array_intersect() - that gives you an array of all the value from $needle that are also in $haystack. I think that's what you were asking for to avoid the if statement:

```
$files = array_intersect($needle, $haystack);
foreach ($files as $value) {
    $filename = "$value.txt";
    file_put_contents($filename, $file);
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a `var_dump($filename);` to the loop, and see if the correct filenames are getting echoed out.

Answer (score 1):

file_put_contents filename is first argument, data second. [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents($filename, $file);
```